# Post Data but GET Method json -ios

Tags: iphone, ios, post, get

how can i use the get method to post data on an api link with 6 values and a json format?

im really fuzzled. im doing this for days . is it best to have 6 textfields that will be used to write the value and a button to indicate post data?

check out my code and please help.

```
-(IBAction)postDataPressed
{

    NSString *urlString = @"http://192.168.18.8/apisample2/friendb.php?fm=jsn";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setPostValue:user.text forKey:@"un"];
    [request setPostValue:pass.text forKey:@"pd"];
    [request setPostValue:gender.text forKey:@"gd"];
    [request setPostValue:age.text forKey:@"ag"];
    [request setPostValue:status.text forKey:@"st"];
    [request setPostValue:lookfor.text forKey:@"lf"];

    [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
    }];
    [request setFailedBlock:^{
        NSError *error = [request error];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)]; 
    [request startAsynchronous];


}
```

i hope someone will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *request_url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://192.168.18.8/apisample2/friendb.php?fm=jsn&un=%@&pd=%@&gd=%@&ag=%@&st=%@&lf=%@",
    user.text, pass.text, gender.text, age.text,status.text,lookfor.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:request_url];
ASIHttpRequest *request = [ASIHttpRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.delegate = self;
....
```

HTTP Get method only accept data in url, called query string, so you have to build query string yourself.

Comment: thank you for you reply. i have tried and modified my code to the one u posted but i am still getting the server error `data query sent, incomplete` do i still lack something? Thanks again.

Comment: Check the transmitted data using NSLog or, even better, using a Proxy like Charles - maybe there are escaping issues (certain characters not being transmitted due to incorrect character encoding).

Comment: @Till - the charles proxy seems to be not opening here. and i checked the fiddler but it is only written in notepad with weird encodings on it. can i have some other way sir? Thanks for the reply.... i really hope i can finish this app

Comment: @Changxing Wang - Thank You so much i have finished my app now