# Sending request to server by JSON

Tags: ios, json, request, textfield

I have problem with UITextField and sending request to my server. This is my situation: I have connection between my APP and server by JSON protocol. I send request by POST method, and i'm sending in this: message JSON. I must send JSON in this form: 
{“pin”:”xxxx”, “uuid”:”yyyy”}. And now it's my question: i wrote pin number in UITextField, but i don't know how to put this pin number which one i wrote in UITextField to my JSON 'message'. I put my code below:

```
ViewController.h:

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>


@property (retain, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *connection;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableData *receivedData;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *uuid;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *htmlSTR;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pinField;

-(IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)ReturnKeyButton:(id)sender;

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSData *json;

@end



ViewController.m:

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // [self uid];

}



-(void) uid{
    NSString *uuid =[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
    NSLog(@"aaaa",uuid);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(IBAction)ReturnKeyButton:(id)sender{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    _receivedData =[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [_receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    // Return nil to indicate not necessary to store a cached response for this connection
    return 0;
}


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[_receivedData length]);
    //NSString *htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   // NSLog(@"%@" , htmlSTR);

   NSError *e = nil;
   NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: self.receivedData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];  
   NSLog(@"data %@",jsonArray);

}




-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    //NSLog(@"%@" , error);
}



- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender {

        NSDictionary *dict =@{@"pin" : @"",
                              @"uuid" : @""};


        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *json;


        if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict])
            {
                //Serializowanie słownika
                json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

                //sprawdzenie czy nie ma żadnych błędów, następnie wypisanie zserializowanego jsona w konsoli
                if (json != nil && error == nil)
                   {
                       NSString *jsonArray = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                       NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonArray);

                   }
            }


        [self.connection cancel];
        NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        self.receivedData = data;
       [self uid];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bottari.digitaltouch.pl/v1/login"]]; 
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:json];
        //NSLog(@"%@",json);
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [json length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        self.connection = connection;
        [connection start];
```

Comment: textfied.text using this you can get textfield text.

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\“pin\”:\”%@\”, \“uuid\”:\”%@\”",textfieldpin.text,strUdid];

Comment: I know about textField.text but if i have pinField(that's my name for textField) and json(that's my serialized object) and i don't know how to put them together. And pinField.text = json doesn't work/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post Data but GET Method json -ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442843/post-data-but-get-method-json-ios)

Comment: Doesn't work for me.